# Getting last 4 digits of a credit card with Stripe client side, is it possible?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I know there is a way to do it server side with

```
stripe.paymentMethods.retrieve
```

Is there a client side alternative?(After a payment is confirmed). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving PaymentMethod is supported with your secret key but not with the publishable key, so it isn't supported from the client-side.

You would set up an endpoint on your backend that your frontend makes a request to, which accepts a PaymentMethod ID and retrieves it. Then it returns the relevant fields back to your frontend.